# Is there any truly free program to recover deleted files on Windows 10 today?

Tags: data-recovery

All "free" solutions I find aren't free, usually you can only recover 500MB of data or something similar. I also find old threads about software that used to be completely free but aren't anymore.

Is there any truly free program that accomplishes data recovery available in 2021?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) are free and OpenSource.

Comment: Thanks, are these command line only? (vs. gui I mean)

Comment: PhotoRec existist in a GUI version. Testdisk has as far as I remember a text based UI.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really compete with Robert's answer as their suggestions are open source but [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) has always worked well for me and an additional feature is that it can do secure delete (writes a bunch of random data over the space).

Answer (score 0):

DMDE is a great solution.  The free version is limited to one folder at a time.

https://dmde.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).